# Area under a curve subintervals

Tags: integration

For the graph $y=-x^2+10x+24$ for $(-1\le x \le 3)$

How many subintervals would I need to estimate the area to within 0.1 unit²

I ended up drawing a crazy graph and came up with 800, which is wrong...

Comment: What integration method do you use?

Comment: I didn't use any. I did it by using upper and lower rectangles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $n$ intervals of equal length $\frac{4}{n}$, an estimate of the area by upper rectangles is given by

$$A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(-1+k \cdot \frac{4}{n}\right)\cdot \frac{4}{n}.$$

Since $f(x) = -x^2+10x+24$, we get

$$A(n) = \frac{4}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[-\left(-1+k \cdot \frac{4}{n}\right)^2 + 10 \left(-1+k \cdot \frac{4}{n}\right) +24\right]$$
or simplified

$$A(n) = \frac{4}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[- k^2 \cdot \frac{16}{n^2} + k \cdot \frac{48}{n}+13\right].$$

We want

$$\left|\int_{-1}^3 f(x) \, dx - A(n)\right| \leq 0.1.$$

Let us simplify the LHS before we solve for $n$. Using

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, \, \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

we can find

$$A(n) = \frac{4}{n} \left( -\frac{8}{n} \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}  + 24(n+1) + 13n\right) = \frac{380n^2+192n-32}{3n^2}$$

and therefore $\int_{-1}^3 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} A(n) = \frac{380}{3}$. Hence the inequality becomes

$$\left|\frac{380}{3} - \frac{380n^2+192n-32}{3n^2} \right|\leq 0.1$$

which eventually yields

$$n \geq 639.833,$$

so $n = 640$ should work.

You can check that $\frac{380}{3} = 126.666\dots$ and for $n = 640$ we get $A(n) \approx 126.76664$ whereas for $n = 639$ we have $A(n) \approx 126.76680$.